# Getting a Measurement Series via Java SDK for Cumulocity

Tags: cumulocity

Is there a method to get measurement series from Cumulocity API using the Java SDK? When using the measurement-API, I only seem to be able to get measurement collections. To prevent unnecessary overhead in the communication I would like to only get the measurement series. Basically, the same result as if I am querying `{{url}}/measurement/measurements/series` via Postman.

Comment: Please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. I have honestly know clue what you are looking for (and note: requests for tools/libraries are off topic here).

Comment: I was told to ask those kind of questions here with the "cumulocity" tag (which this question is about), because cumulocity developers are looking into the questions here. I got good answers before so I thought this was the way to go. I'm sorry if this question confuses you because you may not have any knowledge about cumulocity. I will ask my question clearer next time.

Comment: So this question is about a specific api and not so much about java programming? This is not very clear from your question given the title.

Comment: Exactly. I hopefully fixed it by removing the java tag.

Comment: You can raise a support ticket with a feature request for this. Maybe this finds the way into the SDK one day.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid currently it is not possible get supported series by InventoryApi. You have to call REST method `GET /inventory/managedObjects/<id>/supportedSeries`

**Update 15.01.2019**:
It's now available since 9.20.0.

**Disclaimer:** I'm cumulocity developer.

Comment: That is true, but not exactly what was asked in the question. However getting only the measurement series is not possible as well. You'd have to make a REST API Call.

Answer (score 0):

No, currently `{{url}}/measurement/measurements/series` is most performant API and Java SDK has no method and response object, like measurement api. you still can use platform to get and deserialise response.

```
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class Series {
        private Map<String, List<MinMax>> values;
        private boolean truncated;
        ...
    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class MinMax {
        private float min;
        private float max;
        ...
    }

    String url = "{{url}}/measurement/measurements/series?source={{source}}&series={{series}}&....";
    CumulocityCredentials credentials = new CumulocityCredentials("{{user}}", "{{password}}");
    Platform platform = PlatformImpl("{{url}}", credentials, 5000);
    platform.rest().get(url, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE, Series.class);
```